# Software not recognizing .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, .net, windows-8

I've just set up a new Windows Server 2012. I haven't installed any other Software or Roles yet. The first thing I wanted to install is a sowtware which needs to have .NET 4.5 installed. The Problem is following:

When I try to install the software I get an error that at least .NET 4.0 has to be installed. When I try to install .NET 4.5 I get an error that it is already installed. 
Any older installer of .NET (v4.0 and so on) gives me an error that a higher version of .NET is already installed.

It just seems that the sofware is not able to recognize that .NET alredy is installed.
Is there a possibility to reinstall it so that it maby couls recognize it? Or any other suggestions?

P.S. I'v already seen the same problem hapening on Windows 8. I guess a solution would work for both...

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is a Feature that needs to be installed from Roles and Features (if it isn't already), not from a separate installer. Start the Add Roles and Features wizard and see if .NET 4.5 is already installed. If it isn't then install it from the wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with the application installer.  Obviously they haven't tested this on systems that only have .NET 4.5 installed, such as Windows Server 2012.  Go back to your vendor/developer and have them test this and provide you with an installer package that actually works and that they will support.

More information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684541/why-doesnt-windows-server-2012-support-net-framework-4-0

**Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 blocks Framework 4.0 Downloaded Install**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765375